# Javascript access to private properties via prototype

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

This is pretty silly example, but it definitely describes the problem I constantly stuck with. I have constructor function like this:

```
function Pagination() {
  var page = 1;
}
```

Then I want to assign methods to its prototype:

```
(function () {
  this.page = function () {
      // Here goes code
  };
}).call(Pagination.prototype);
```

Are there any ways to get that private property `page`?

Comment: 1. No, "private properties" are realised through function scope, and there's no way to change how function scope works. Think twice about whether you *really* needs those properties to be "private" and why. 2. That's an odd bending over backwards with the prototype there IMO.

Comment: @deceze Well I thought it would be nice to move all methods to its prototype instead of keeping them in the constructor. But on the other hand I still need encapsulation. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: "Private" properties and prototype simply doesn't go together in Javascript. The thing I always keep repeating in this situation is: *why* exactly do you **"need"** such encapsulation?

Comment: @deceze I'm creating logic, which will be reused few times in the future and I'm not the only one who works on the project. So I'd like to provide as much interfaces as possible so it works as expected.

Comment: Typically the "we're all consenting adults here" approach should suffice, and you name your private properties `_page` or something similar and agree not to touch those. Perhaps even better: use TypeScript and mark them up as `private` so tsc throws errors. If you need to become so defensive that you need to "actually" make the properties inaccessible, you're in a bad spot to start from.